# Why is the dockerfile not able to COPY?

Tags: reactjs, docker

I'm creating simple React app with Docker image but for some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat build: file does not exist
```

Here's the dockerfile:

```
FROM /httpd:2.4.38

ENV SRVROOT=/usr/local/apache2

ENV myapp=$SRVROOT/myapp

COPY /app/build $myapp
COPY /Docker/run.sh $SRVROOT
COPY /Docker/httpd.conf $SRVROOT/conf/

RUN chmod 755 $SRVROOT/run.sh

CMD ["/usr/local/apache2/run.sh"]
```

Comment: And where's your "build" configuration?

Comment: Is this correct? `/mygapp` not `/myapp`?

Comment: Is the error message correct?  I'm guessing you're running `docker build .` (or maybe with some other path at the end); are the `app` and `Docker` directories subdirectories of the current directory (or the other directory you specify)?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to COPY is the location of the file on the host machine. The leading slash means you’re trying to copy from `/app` and `/Dockerfile` (at the root of your computer), which is outside Docker context. Those files should be relative to the current directory:

```
COPY ./app/build $myapp
COPY ./Docker/run.sh $SRVROOT
COPY ./Docker/httpd.conf $SRVROOT/conf/
```

Comment: sadly it didn't help

Comment: Docker does some normalization on file paths which can be unintuitive.  Something that's apparently an absolute path as in the original question is still interpreted as relative to the build-context directory.  So, perhaps surprisingly, `COPY /app/build`, `COPY ./app/build`, and even `COPY ../../app/build` all copy the same thing.

Comment: Huh. Today I learned!

Comment: Do each of those directories exist on your computer? `app/build`, `Docker/run.sh`, `Docker/httpd.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

The `--from` flag is used for `multi-stage` builds. It does not look like this is your case. Try removing the `--from` flag from your `dockerfile`

Comment: I tried it but it didn;t help :/

Comment: I believe the error should be different without the `--from` flag. Could u update your question with latest error?

Comment: I accidentally copied old code, so the error is actually without the --from flag

Answer (score -2):

Try using their relative path for the files you want to copy
Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).